# Calculating field in empty table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.3, field-calculator

Using Arc 10.3.1 ModelBuilder, I need to populate a .dbf field (pfo_pct) with a variable value using the Calculate Field tool. However, the .dbf is an empty table (no records) and I get a Warning 000405: No records within table.  The same problem happens outside of ModelBuilder when I try to Field Calculate on an empty table.

I believe that the problem could be resolved if I could insert an empty record into the .dbf prior to the field calculation, but I don't see any tools that accomplish that, nor any environment settings that would help.

Sadly, I am not proficient with Python...

Comment: What is the tool supposed to do? Is it a single value, or is it calculated for each geometry/shape/object in an existing attribute table? If you can't add it to the existing table (after adding a new field), you're going have to populate the new table with however many rows you need before performing the calculation.

Comment: The way I would add a row to an empty table is by using `arcpy.da.InsertCursor`.

Comment: This really doesn't make *any* sense.  You can't `UPDATE` a field value in an empty table -- because it's **empty**.  Is this dBase table associated with a shapefile?

Comment: @Vince You are correct - the table is empty.  As I mentioned in the OP, the problem would be solved if I *could* insert a row in the table, and that was the essence of my question.  It appears that PolyGeo has that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would add a row to an empty table is by using `arcpy.da.InsertCursor`.

Alternatively, keep a one row table somewhere so that you can Copy it, and then use the Calculate Field tool to update its one row.